# PXE-T00 filename too long

Tags: pxe-boot, fortinet

I'm using a fortinet router as the dhcp server, I have option 67 defined as pxelinux.0 in hexa, it works fine for VMs and my own computer, they boot on PXE just fine.
Now I have an other computer I'd like to boot on network with, but it says PXE-T00 filename too long. When I look into the logs of tftp-hpa on the tftp server, I get that :

```
Sep 25 17:34:46 SRVPXE in.tftpd[17718]: RRQ from 192.168.0.1 filename pxelinux.0M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?
```

For some reason, that computer doesn't like the filename and puts half a console of bad character after it when requesting to the tftp server. Any idea of how to solve that ? I'm guessing it must be requesting the filename including the padding ? I did try to add a lot of 0 after my dhcp option in my hexa decimal string, but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Well I lied, after checking the fortinet did not save my lot of 0 after the filename try, so I tried it again and it works.
Here is the option 67 that works for me :

```
set option2 67 '7078656c696e75782e3000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
```